# Scrape data from a website using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am still quite amateur at python, I am trying to scrape data from a website using selenium

```
 <small class="fxs_price_ohl"> <span>Open 1.29814</span> <span>High 1.29828</span> <span>Low 1.29775</span> </small> </div> </div> </li> <script type="application/ld+json">
```

trying to obtain the data Open 1.29814, High 1.29828 and Low 1.29775 from the html code above^

```
count_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//small[@class='fxs_price_ohl']//span")
print(count_element.text)
```

I'm using selenium with python, this is my code ^
But count_element.text prints empty, how to get the data Open 1.29814, High 1.29828 and Low 1.29775

Answer (score 0):

Use

> "find_element**s**_by_xpath"

if you want to retrieve multiple elements.

```
count_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//small[@class='fxs_price_ohl']//span")
for ele in count_elements:
    print(ele.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a css selector of class for the parents with descendant combinator and type selector for the child spans but you also need a wait condition as page is slow loading

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/gbpusd')
before_text = ''

while True: #this could be improved with a timeout
    elements = [i for i in WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fxs_chart_cag_cont .fxs_price_ohl span")))]
    elem = elements[-1]
    if elem.text != before_text:
        break
print([elem.text for elem in elements])
```

Comment: I still couldn't get the result:c

Comment: I updated answer. – please let me know if this has resolved any problems you were having.